# How can I mark the end of a C string?

Tags: c++, c

Here is the code for the function:

```
void pattern(char word[200], char asPattern[200]) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++) { // unsigned to remove warning
        if (strchr("aeiou", word[i]) != 0) asPattern[i] = '*';
        else asPattern[i] = '#';
}
```

Basically this function replaces consonants in word with #'s and vowels with *'s, and stores the new pattern in the asPattern string. However, if I display the asPattern on the screen, it shows the correct pattern followed by a bunch of unknown symbols (strlen(asPattern) equals 211 or something after the for loop). 
I believe the problem is that the asPattern's end isn't marked and
    asPattern[strlen(asPattern)] = '/0' 
doesn't work and I don't know what else to do...

I cannot use the std::string, so please bear with me and use C strings.

Comment: It's backslash rather than slash.

Comment: You didn't mention whether you can use the algorithm functions.  They work with char arrays also, not just `std::string`.

Comment: I would suggest removing C++ tag as this question has nothing to do with C++.

Comment: Your code will not work if the vowel is a capital letter.

Comment: Read a book on C and lookup "strings". You'll readily find the answer.

Answer (score 6):

add the code

```
asPattern[strlen(word)] = '\0';
```

either before or after the for-loop

Comment: In general I would recommend to use `asPattern[strlen(asPattern)]`. That is, you are setting the NUL character at the end of `asPattern`, so use `strlen()` on `asPattern`, not on `word`. I know they are expected to have the same length, but sometimes the code doesn't do what you expect (think of a more complicated function), and in that case it's better to have a safer approach. For the same reason I would put this line *after* the for loop, when the substitution is over. Then you don't work on what you *expect*: you work on what you *have*.

Comment: @FabioTurati And how would the `strlen` work on the not-yet terminated string?

Comment: @FabioTurati `asPattern[strlen(asPattern)]` will crash.

Comment: @FabioTurati not sure i agree with first part, but certainly agree with after the for-loop and I would still use `asPattern[strlen(word)]` since asPattern hasn't been terminated yet.

Comment: @FabioTurati if I use strlen() on asPattern, its size grows to over 200 (which exceeds the limit of 200 that I set) and I don't know why. Using strlen() on word seems to work though.

Comment: @AndreiIndricut It won't work because the `asPattern` is not terminated.

Comment: @EugeneSh. and everybody: god, I'm stupid. You are completely right, sorry. To use my approach one would have to know the length by some other means. Clearly it makes no sense here.

Answer (score 2):

C-strings are terminated by null character, which can be represented by literal 0 or '\0'. Functions that work with C-strings (like strlen) expects that. Note that `strlen()` scans string for null character, so your loop:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)
```

is ineffective - `strlen()` has to scan `word` on every iteration. So better code could be:

```
void pattern(char word[200], char asPattern[200]) {
    const unsigned len = strlen(word);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < len; i++) { // unsigned to remove warning
        if (strchr("aeiou", word[i]) != 0) asPattern[i] = '*';
        else asPattern[i] = '#';
    }
    asPattern[len] = 0; // or '\0' if you prefer
}
```

Comment: Nice to use `len = strlen(word)` to prevent calling `strlen()` so many times as in OP's code.

Comment: Recommend calling the `'\0'` the _null character_ rather than _NULL character_ as `NULL` is better reserved for the _null pointer constant_.

Comment: `nullptr` does not exist in C.  It does exist in C++.  Although post is tagged both languages, certainly appears C-ish.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest, almost foolproof solution is just set the entire block of characters to `\0`.  This works correctly, assuming you have prior knowledge of the actual size of the char array.

```
#include <string.h>
void pattern(char word[200], char asPattern[200]) 
{
    memset(asPattern, '\0', 200);  // we are assuming that there really are 200  bytes
    //...
}
```

Once you do this, then you need not worry about the null terminator.

Also, note that this:

```
void pattern(char word[200], char asPattern[200])
```

is no different than this:

```
void pattern(char* word, char* asPattern)
```

So actually, that function doesn't really know how big `asPattern` is.  So again, if you know up front what the size is, and you know that you will be overwriting the string anyway, just use `memset` and forget the headaches of whether you should be using `strlen()` or whatever other scheme there might be to figure out where the null byte goes.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your function and it works fine. (here is the snippet: http://rextester.com/XDSU30889)

the "asPattern" must be sent to the function cleared from any content (it must be full with `'\0'`-s, that's what the `GlobalAlloc()` does if you're on Windows, otherwise use `malloc()` then `memset()`